# How to pass a parameter of a .exe made in VB .net to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, exe

I'm trying to pass a parameter how the title says this is the .exe app I have made with VB .net, this is the app I have made, wich send the letter "P" and recibe the weight, when the button is pressed simply convert to integer and use the "Environment.ExitCode = IntegerVal" to return a value to the javascript that is running it.

```
  Imports System
  Imports System.IO.Ports
  Imports System.ComponentModel

  Public Class Form1
      Dim Test As String
      Dim DoublelVal As Double
      Dim IntegerVal As Integer

      Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiveing of data
'------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SerialPort1.PortName = "COM5"
    SerialPort.GetPortNames()
    SerialPort1.Open()
    SerialPort1.Write("P")
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    DoublelVal = CDbl(Val(Test))
    IntegerVal = Convert.ToInt32(DoublelVal * 1000)        
    SerialPort1.Close()
    MsgBox(IntegerVal)
    Environment.ExitCode = IntegerVal
    Me.Close()        
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
    If Me.RichTextBox2.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Test = Trim(text)                        
        Me.RichTextBox2.Text &= Test            
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

What I'm trying to do is use the "Environment.ExitCode = IntegerVal" to return a value to this javascript:

```
<script languaje="text/javascript"> 
function runFile(){
var File = "C:\\Users\\luisrodrigo\\Desktop\\SerialCom\\SerialCom\\bin\\Debug\\SerialCom.exe";
var ExeActive = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var Flag = ExeActive.run(File,1,true); 
$s('P120_OUTPUT',Flag);
}
</script>
```

So the javascript it is working but only on IE (I know it suck but that was the request) because it's using ActiveX, the javascript expect the "ExitCode" and when I run the exe from local it does send me the weight correctly but when I run it on web(using the JavaScript Function) it returns 0.

When I run the vb .net in Visual Studio 2013 on the Output from Debug (The screen of the bottom) send as follow:

```
 The program '[1068] SerialCom.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 The program '[1068] SerialCom.vshost.exe' has exited with code 255 (0xff).
```

As we can see it send the exit code two times, so my guess its the JavaScript Function it's getting the first returning code insted of the second one, the one that I need.

So the question is, how did pass the variable "IntegerVal" from vb to the variable "Flag" in JavaScript?

Thanks for yor time.

Comment: I notice in your javascript block, you spelt language wrong... Try fixing that and seeing if that's the issue.

Comment: The JavaScript is working fine, thanks for letting me know about my miss spell, but thats not it.